# Remove file from remote server with Robot framework

Tags: automation, robotframework

I'm making an automation testcase that need to upload a file to SFTP server, do something and remove this file on teardown. It quite easy for me to upload file by using Put File on SSH Library but meet trouble with removal. SSH Library not supports keyword to remove file and I can't find something useful for this subject anywhere.

Tks a lot!

Comment: Maybe use the OS Library? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Remove%20File Try and connect to the remote environment and try to make use of this library?

Comment: @Goralight: you can't use the OS library to run a keyword on a remote system.

Comment: You need to use "Execute command" keyword to remove file on server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Pekka, you can use [Execute Command](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html#Execute%20Command) to remove files from remote server

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SSHLibrary 

*** Test Cases ***
Open Connection And Remove files
    Open Connection    ${HOST}
    Login    ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
    ${FileList}=    List Directory    ${DIR}
    log    ${FileList}
    ${rc}=    Execute Command    rm ${DIR}/${FILE}
    Should Be Equal    ${rc}    ${0}
    Close All Connections
```

Comment: That's only useful if the account has SSH access. It'd be great if the SSHLibrary had a Delete File function that worked over a SFTP connection.